# Do I give only the read-only RDS database permission for an aws lambda code, when I create custom role and edit the policy document this way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I want to create an aws lambda code, which provides a public API for only read from an aws rds db instance. When I want to create a lambda function, it asks me about permission roles. Because I'm afraid, I want to give a very strict permission to the code to allow only the reading from the db instance.

I have found [this](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/55b358748be3c314f956) site, it lists a few managed policies. I could find this inside that:

```
"AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess": {
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess",
    "AttachmentCount": 0,
    "CreateDate": "2015-02-06T18:40:53+00:00",
    "DefaultVersionId": "v1",
    "Document": {
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "rds:Describe*",
                    "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                    "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                    "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                    "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                    "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Action": [
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
    },
    "IsAttachable": true,
    "IsDefaultVersion": true,
    "Path": "/",
    "PolicyId": "ANPAJKTTTYV2IIHKLZ346",
    "PolicyName": "AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess",
    "UpdateDate": "2015-02-06T18:40:53+00:00",
    "VersionId": "v1"
},
```

I can see the default policy document, when I want to create a new custom role. And I can see that is basically contains {"Statement", "Version" and "Resource"}:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this perfectly fits to the AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess's "Document" block, so I think that needs to be copy-pasted to there to achieve the rds read-only permission. So what I need to put into the custom role's policy document is:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "rds:Describe*",
                "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

This is the thing I need to do? Am I right? 
Does it allow me for the lambda function to read only from a certain RDS db instance? Is there a more simple way to do this? 
Because I saw the policy templates in the "create new role from template", and I couldn't find anything for this goal.

Comment: I think you may be confusing IAM permissions with read-only permissions for an SQL user. Are trying to secure access to your data? or to the RDS instance only?

Comment: @RodrigoM I heard it's bad to use mysql api from the client application and connect to the database, because potential hackers could get login credentials from the app/from the communication line and clear the whole db, etc. 
So I got an advice to use AWS Lambda to provide an api for only to read from the db and use the lambda with aws mobile SDK. 
The answer is the RDS instance only, I think.

Comment: The IAM policies for RDS are grant/deny access for *management* of the service only.

Comment: @RodrigoM But don't I need to grant access for management of the rds for the task?

Comment: @RodrigoM if I understand this correctly, the IAM role tells people can run that certain lambda code with RDSreadonlypermission, and we doesn't allow that script to run with any other permission. We doesn't allow to a lambda script to access to any other AWS service(ec2, DynamoDB, etc.), or write into the RDS db instance. This can be the "first layer of security". 
The other layer of security is obviously the public read method of the code, which only reads from the RDS db instance, and doesn't provide public method for clear the db, or anything else. This is the "second layer of security".

Comment: Yes exactly. Limit the lambda to *Describe,*List access to RDS. And expose the lambda via API for another security layer. Then, create a user with the correct access to read/write the DB as need.

Comment: @RodrigoM After this comment of yours I'm confused. 
"Limit the lambda to *Describe,*List access to RDS"
Do I need to somehow modify this policy document I posted in the question? If yes, how exactly?
The IAM user and the RDS db instance are already created.

Comment: Sorry no change is needed. That policy is reasonable restrictive with the given policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IAM policies, like the one you shown above, are grant/deny access for *management* of the RDS service only. That does not grant you authorization to access data. You can consider the following security approach for securing the DB again unauthorized access.

1. Secure the Lambda Execution Role - give the lambda service least privleged role for accessing the RDS management service.
2. Secure the RDS login user - Create a user dedicated for this function, and grant it the least privedge required to access the DB and perform the needed functions
3. Secure the Lambda via API. You can use the AWS API Gateway to expose the Lambda function.  This API can further secured against unauthorized access. This is optional.

Comment: Using the AWS Mobile SDK isn't enough to securely call the Lambda public methods? Maybe the only problem would be with it is the number of calling, and maybe the API Gateway would restrict that. Would be this the only problem?

Comment: I refer in the previous comment to the 3rd point of your answer.

Comment: I do not know the SDK well, but it can certainly secure a call to Lambda - Secure the Lambda itself as suggested, and that's a good approach.

Comment: So using the AWS Mobile SDK for call Lambda makes your 3. point completed? Or do I need to use AWS Api Gateway near the SDK? 

And how exactly secure the api gateway the calling of lambda?

Comment: Yes if you follow good security passwords there - re gateway that may be better handled in a new question.